# How to store output of stored procedure in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to store the output of below query in a table but I am not able to store and when i create temporary table to store the output it gives me as such access denied.Please if you can help me it will be very great full.

```
        DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE air1(p_lname VARCHAR(50))
    BEGIN
    select
       ( SELECT @airtel:=testValue FROM airtel WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from airtel)) as airtel,
        (SELECT @idea:=testValue  FROM idea WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from idea)) as idea,
        (SELECT @jio:=testValue  FROM jio WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from jio)) as jio,
        (SELECT @voda:=testValue FROM voda WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from voda))  as voda,
        (select @airtel1:=count(operator_id)  from airtel where testValue < @airtel)as airtelpercentcount,
        (select @idea1:=count(operator_id)  from idea where testValue < @idea)as ideapercentcount,
        (select @jio1:=count(operator_id)  from jio where testValue < @jio)as jiopercentcount,
        (select @voda1:=count(operator_id)  from voda where testValue < @voda)as vodapercentcount,
        (select @airtel2:=count(operator_id) from airtel) as airtelcount,
        (select @idea2:=count(operator_id) from idea) as ideacount,
        (select @jio2:=count(operator_id) from jio) as jiocount,
        (select @voda2:=count(operator_id) from voda) as vodacount,
        (select ((@airtel1/@airtel2)*100))as airtelpercentage,
        (select ((@idea1/@idea2)*100))as ideapercentage,
        (select ((@jio1/@jio2)*100))as jiopercentage,
        (select ((@voda1/@voda2)*100))as vodapercentage;
        insert into julyoutput(airtel,idea,jio,voda,airtelpercentcount,ideapercentcount,jiopercentcount,vodapercentcount,airtelcount,ideacount,jiocount,vodacount,airtelpercent,ideapercent,jiopercent,vodapercent)
        select airtel,idea,jio,voda,airtelpercentcount,ideapercentcount,jiopercentcount,vodapercentcount,airtelcount,ideacount,jiocount,vodacount,airtelpercent,ideapercent,jiopercent,vodapercent from julyoutput ;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Have you checked with db admin that you have such privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be something like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE air1(p_lname VARCHAR(50))
    BEGIN
    select
       ( SELECT @airtel:=testValue FROM airtel WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from airtel)) as airtel,
        (SELECT @idea:=testValue  FROM idea WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from idea)) as idea,
        (SELECT @jio:=testValue  FROM jio WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from jio)) as jio,
        (SELECT @voda:=testValue FROM voda WHERE rank = (select round(count(rank)*p_lname) from voda))  as voda,
        (select @airtel1:=count(operator_id)  from airtel where testValue < @airtel)as airtelpercentcount,
        (select @idea1:=count(operator_id)  from idea where testValue < @idea)as ideapercentcount,
        (select @jio1:=count(operator_id)  from jio where testValue < @jio)as jiopercentcount,
        (select @voda1:=count(operator_id)  from voda where testValue < @voda)as vodapercentcount,
        (select @airtel2:=count(operator_id) from airtel) as airtelcount,
        (select @idea2:=count(operator_id) from idea) as ideacount,
        (select @jio2:=count(operator_id) from jio) as jiocount,
        (select @voda2:=count(operator_id) from voda) as vodacount,
        (select @airtelpercentage:=((@airtel1/@airtel2)*100))as airtelpercentage,
        (select @ideapercentage:=((@idea1/@idea2)*100))as ideapercentage,
        (select @jiopercentage:=((@jio1/@jio2)*100))as jiopercentage,
        (select @vodapercentage:=((@voda1/@voda2)*100))as vodapercentage;
        insert into julyoutput(airtel,idea,jio,voda,airtelpercentcount,ideapercentcount,jiopercentcount,vodapercentcount,airtelcount,ideacount,jiocount,vodacount,airtelpercent,ideapercent,jiopercent,vodapercent)
        select @airtel,@idea,@jio,@voda,@airtel1,@idea1,@jio1,@voda1,@airtel2,@idea2,@jio2,@voda2:,@airtelpercentage,@ideapercentagedeapercent,@jiopercentage,@vodapercentage  ;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Rank becomes a reserved word in version 8.0.2 - it might be better to back tick it in the query.

Comment: it is working luca-lupidi. Thank you soo much for the help